# amCharts number format (Thousand Format)

Tags: amcharts, amstock

I am using amCharts Stock Chart.

How to format the numbers on value axis? Currently it shows me `5,218,923.96` and I need value like `52,18,923.96`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to achieve custom formatting like this is to use [`labelFunction`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/ValueAxis#labelFunction) on your value axis.

You can set it to a custom function, which will take the value and re-format it to your own format using your own logic:

```
"panels": [{
  // ...
  "valueAxes": [{
    "labelFunction": function(value) {
      // reformat and return the value
      // ...
      return value;
    }
  }]
}]
```